# No me lee la ultima rama del arbol de datos ( ``this.state.profile.notes.list`` )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

Tengo un arbol con algunos datos

```
console.log(this.state.profile.notes.tags)
```

Pero me sale que no esta definido, pero cuando voy a `profile.notes`, se ve que tiene la siguiente rama `tags`.

Esto es lo que muestra cuando retorno `this.state.profile.notes`, y aun asi no me deja leer `list` ni `tags`:

[image: [![Imagen de lo que me muestra profile]

Comment: Bueno ambas propiedades representan arrays, intenta `this.state.profile.notes.tags.length`

Comment: Siento no haber podido contestar antes, me sigue saliendo que tags no esta definido

Comment: acabo de arreglar el problema, tenia que definir en el state, el objeto entero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacia falta añadir ese objeto entero en el state, porque el componente no resivia Tags hasta que lo cargara de la base de datos y no estaba todo el objeto en el state, solo es eso